# Is it possible to have timing issue with a DS18B20 1-wire temp sensor on ESP32 with arduino?

Tags: esp32, 1wire, arduino-esp32

i have and ESP32 module that i have a DS18B20 sensor connected to with a 4.7k pullup resistor. the problem is that i get very inconsistent reading a lot of -127 readings in my current program. With WiFi running, Asynch mqtt, websocket etc running on the esp. what i found strange is that when i try the test program, it seems to be pretty consistent, but the test program doesn't start wifi or anything else. Also we have motor VFD near the device and when a motor start, i stop getting readings completely. I have now very confused about all that. Is there anyone that can have any insigth or recommendation about that? I am starting to think maybe a got a fake DS18B20 this is why it is so picky. I have some hundreds of the, and they seems to be all pretty inconsistent ?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Hi Martin, we can't help you without your code and console output. Please post it as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I understand but the question is does the 1-wire can have timing issue on the ESP32 if a lot is goin into the CPU ? The code is very complicated. Or is there a best practice for 1-wire on ESP32 ?

Comment: Simplify the code to demonstrate the problem. Try writing a program that only reads from the sensor. Does it still have the problem? Then it's not a timing issue.

Comment: Looks like it is hardware issues